# Windows 8 sleeps minutes after full screen video ends

Tags: windows-8, sleep

Whenever full screen video is playing, for instance, youtube, twitch, VLC or XBMC, sleep is prevented, but it seems like the idle timer still ticks down to zero which means the minute the video ends, the computer almost immediately goes to sleep.

I'd like to change this behaviour so that instead of simply preventing sleep, the idle timer should be reset.

Running windows 8, with "Hybrid sleep" enabled.

My current power settings are:-

- Sleep

  - Sleep after: 30 minutes
  - Allow hybrid sleep: On
  - Allow wake timers: Enable
- Multimedia settings

  - When sharing media: Prevent idling to sleep
  - When playing video: Optimise video quality

Comment: Thats’ not how the power-management works. When a software like a video-player runs, it blocks the power-management from working at all; the timer should not be running at all. Your questions says that it sleeps *minutes* after the video ends, but also that it happens almost immediately. Which is it? How fast does it happen? If it really does happen minutes later, then you should check how long your system is configured to wait before sleeping; it may be an unusual number that is making it look *like* something strange is happening.

Comment: @russ: Could you please [run `powercfg -energy`](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/quick-tip-create-an-energy-use-report-in-windows-7-with-powercfg/2524/) and post the results.

Comment: @harrymc Thanks for the response, the HTML output file can be found here: [link](http://tinyurl.com/p4huw26)

Comment: @Synetech Approximately one minute after the end of a long youtube video, or a VLC video, or any other content that ends without user interaction, the computer will go into standby mode.  This is definitely not the same behaviour as if I leave my computer idle.  This is the same mode as Standby from Windows shutdown dialog.

Comment: Consider the possibility that "When playing video" means something a lot more specific than what you or I think of (i.e. this might mean "when microsoft windows media player version NN.NN is playing video"). Check to see if VLC or youtube in a browser actually trigger this condition.

Comment: This is an interesting case, but you’ll need to perform a few diagnostic tests to figure out what the problem is. • Define “approximately one minute after the end of a long youtube video”; use a clock and calculate exactly how long to the second, also check if it *always* the same amount of time • Does it happen *only* after long videos? *How* long? What about shorter video? • What happens if you happen to press a key or move the mouse during the video? • Check the *Event Viewer* to see the [reason for the last sleep](http://i.stack.imgur.com/g408S.png) event.

Answer (score 1):

Try these steps:-

1. Go to control panel and power options.
2. Select the Power plan currently active or select the one you want to use and click Change plan settings.
3. Select Advanced settings.
4. Go to Multimedia settings and select your preferred settings.

Basically for your requirement you need to choose Optimise power settings under When playing videos.

Comment: My current settings in this dialog are:
When sharing media: Prevent idling to sleep
When playing video: Optimise video quality

Comment: Does the problem still persists?